# Is it possible to add multiple constraints on a column inside of CREATE TABLE?

Tags: mysql, constraints

I see this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html, but I don't understand how to read this document.

I want to make something like `CREATE TABLE child_table(id VARCHAR(55) PRIMARY KEY AND FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES parent_table.id)`

But I'm not sure if this is possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible. You simply list the constraints on the field, or add multiple table-level constraint declarations.

You can't declare a foreign key inline in MySQL, so your **`CREATE TABLE`** would have to look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE child_table
(
  id VARCHAR(55) PRIMARY KEY,
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES parent_table(id)
);
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE child_table
(
  id VARCHAR(55),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES parent_table(id)
);
```

Comment: Can't do it in one line? Oh well.

Comment: You *can* do, say, `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY` OR `NOT NULL DEFAULT 10`; you just can't do `FOREIGN KEY` or `CHECK` on one line.